# Pandas Dataframe to find sum of difference local max and min

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with increasing values but the series gets reset when there is server restart.

For example

value = {10, 25, 100, 2, 12, 35, 5, 16}

I need to find the sum of the difference of local max and min values

The answer for the above set would be (100-10) + (35-2) + (16-5) = 90 + 33 + 11 = 134

How do I get this done in pandas dataframe ? Appreciate the help

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two step process.

First to get the first and last digits of each increment:

```
df2 = df.groupby((df['col1'].shift()>df['col1']).cumsum()).nth([0,-1])
```

Then to get the difference of each group then sum:

```
df2.groupby(level = 0).diff().sum()
0    134.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` for that:

```py
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import numpy as np

value =np.array( [10, 25, 100, 2, 12, 35, 5, 16] )

max_=value[argrelextrema(value, np.greater)]
min_=value[argrelextrema(value, np.less)]

res=sum(max_)-sum(min_)

#just to include first el:
if(value[0]>value[1]): res+=value[0]
elif(value[0]<value[1]): res-=value[0]
#and the last one:
if(value[-1]>value[-2]): res+=value[-1]
elif(value[-1]<value[-2]): res-=value[-1]

print(res) #134
```